# Write Unit test case for below function- node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I have created a function and need to test it
File `name-abc.js`:

```js
a: function (cb) {
  return function (err, res) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    return cb(null, res);
  };
},
```

File name-abc_test.js

```
describe('test function,()=>{
    it('test',(done)=>{
      // HOW TO TEST THE ABOVE FUNCTION.. WHAT ARGUMENTS SHOULD BE PASSES AS CALLBACK 
      })
    })
```

What arguments should i pass while calling this function and on what values should i assert on.

Comment: I don't see any Java in this question, so I'm removing the `java` tag. Please note that Java and JavaScript are unrelated languages.

Comment: Does a class or an object contain `a` method? Please provide the code

Comment: Please [edit] your questions to include any research you've done on the subject (for instance, the parts of the documentation you've read). Right now, your test file has a syntax error (no end quote after `'test function`).

Comment: @slideshowp2 var obj={
a: function (cb) {
  return function (err, res) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    return cb(null, res);
  };
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [assert](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) of Node.js as your assertion library. And, create a mock or stub for the `callback` function, pass it in `obj.a()` method. At the end, assert that if the `callback` function is to be called with correct parameters.

E.g.

`name-abc.js`:

```js
const obj = {
  a: function (cb) {
    return function (err, res) {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      return cb(null, res);
    };
  },
};

module.exports = obj;
```

`name-abc.test.js`:

```js
const obj = require('./name-abc');
const assert = require('assert');

describe('66636577', () => {
  it('should handle error', () => {
    const callArgs = [];
    const mCallback = (err, res) => {
      callArgs.push([err, res]);
    };
    const mError = new Error('network');
    obj.a(mCallback)(mError);
    assert(callArgs[0][0] === mError && callArgs[0][1] === undefined, 'expect callback to be called with error');
  });

  it('should success', () => {
    const callArgs = [];
    const mCallback = (err, res) => {
      callArgs.push([err, res]);
    };
    const mRes = 'teresa teng';
    obj.a(mCallback)(null, mRes);
    assert(callArgs[0][0] === null && callArgs[0][1] === 'teresa teng', 'expect callback to be called with response');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  66636577
    ✓ should handle error
    ✓ should success


  2 passing (4ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 name-abc.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```